Understanding Tkinter window, and Canvas sizes
I can’t get any information on exactly how window and canvas sizes work in Tkinter.
If I create a window, I can set its size using either the .configure() method or the .geometry() method. If I set both, the .geometry() method appears to override the .configure() method, and I know I can also set the position using the .geometry() method.
I can also create a Canvas object and pack it inside the window. Regardless of the size I set for the canvas, either too large or too small, it still fits neatly inside the window.
Here is a code snippet to illustrate my experiments:
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.configure(background='#ECECEC', padx=20, pady=20)
root.geometry('800x600+200+200')
root.configure(width=1200, height=700)

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=600, height=1400, background='white')
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()

What’s the relationship between the window .configure() and .geometry() methods, and how should this affect the included canvas?

You might find this interesting.

Every widget has a natural size; sometime's its obvious (such as a Button or Label being just big enough to hold its text), sometimes you have to explicitly set it (such as a Canvas or Text, which are expected to have changing contents).  But the geometry manager you use to make the widget visible can override that - here, the fill parameter to .pack() says to ignore the natural size, and instead make the widget fit the window.
